# What is the difference between IMU and IRU?

Tags: gyroscopic-instruments, inertial-nav-system

During my academic studies, I am studying the INS part. First of all, INS means a comprehensive category combined with IRU and inertial navigation computer. The IRU is a sensor that uses a gyroscope and accelerometer to detect rotational attitude changes.

But the problem is the IMU. It is written that the IMU also works by detecting changes in the attitude of the aircraft, including the gyroscope, accelerometer, and even the magnetometer.

So, are IRU and IMU the same concept? I looked elsewhere, but I couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like IMU is a generic name and they both are interchangeable.

From Wikipedia: An IMU (inertial measurement unit) is an electronic device that measures and reports a body's specific force, angular rate, and sometimes the orientation of the body, using a combination of accelerometers, gyroscopes, and sometimes magnetometers.

IMUs are often incorporated into Inertial Navigation Systems which utilize the raw IMU measurements to calculate attitude, angular rates, linear velocity and position relative to a global reference frame.

Source: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertial_measurement_unit

[Here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertial_reference_unit) says: Another name often used interchangeably with IRU is Inertial Measurement Unit.